# Why can't convert string to int with value got by go-redis?

Tags: list, go, redis, type-conversion, go-redis

I'm using [go-redis](https://github.com/go-redis/redis) in go to get list data from Redis.

```
IDs, err := redisClient.LRange("ID", 0, -1).Result()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(IDs)

for _, ID := range IDs {
    id, _ := strconv.Atoi(ID)
    fmt.Println(id)
}
```

In the first print, it can get right data:

```
37907

61357

45622

69007
```

But the second print got all 0:

```
0

0

0

0
```

If don't convert to int, it's string:

```
cannot use ID (type string) as type int in argument
```

So I want to use it as an integer.

---

I tested with a pure list in go:

```
var a [4]string
a[0] = "1"
a[1] = "2"
a[2] = "3"
a[3] = "4"
for _, i := range a {
    id, _ := strconv.Atoi(i)
    fmt.Println(id)
}
```

It can work without separate with new line:

```
1
2
3
4
```

So the `go-redis`'s `.LRange("ID", 0, -1).Result()` returns not only string.
https://godoc.org/github.com/go-redis/redis#Client.LRange
It's `*StringSliceCmd`. How to conver it then?

Comment: Check the error returned from `strconv.Atoi`, it will usually contain info on why it failed to parse the string. Also your `fmt.Println` inside the loop is printing `IDs`, not `id`, that's a typo in the question I assume but if it isn't that might be your problem. And for debugging try printing the individual strings with `fmt.Printf("%q\n", ID)` this will show you also non-printable characters, like whitespace, that the string may contain and which may cause the conversion to fail.

Comment: There may be some extra char in the strings check error

Comment: My bad. It should be `fmt.Println(id)` inside loop. I printed convert error. It was because of wrong type. `.LRange("ID", 0, -1).Result()` returns `[]string`. It should be converted to `ids := strings.Fields(strings.Join(IDs, ""))` then loop `ids`.

Comment: @iooi Please Post an answer and mark it as solved. This will help other users with the same problem to easier find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of wrong type.

`.LRange("ID", 0, -1).Result()` returns `[]string`. It should be converted to `ids := strings.Fields(strings.Join(IDs, ""))` then loop ids.